# batch file variable problems

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am having problems with variables transferring throughout my batch file.

This is a rough example of what I have:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:one
set variableone=outputone
set variabletwo=outputtwo
set variablethree=outputthree
goto two

:two
set /a variable%variableone%four=numberone
set /a variable%variabletwo%five=numbertwo
set /a variable%variablethree%six=numberthree
goto three

:three
set /a variable%variableone%four+=(2*(!variable%variabletwo%five!-!!variable%variablethree%six!)
echo !variable%variableone%four!
exit
```

It is a lot longer than that and this is just a simplified version of what it actually is, however, the variables in the label ":three" won't transfer down so the variable ends up blank which leaves the equation blank as well. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's tremendously difficult to see what you are doing.

In the below code, I've replaced the variable names `NUMBER*` with values.

I've also added the missing close-parenthesis and I'm wondering about the two successinve <kbd>!</kbd>

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:one
set variableone=outputone
set variabletwo=outputtwo
set variablethree=outputthree
goto two

:two
set /a variable%variableone%four=numberone
set /a variable%variabletwo%five=numbertwo
set /a variable%variablethree%six=numberthree
set /a variable%variableone%four=14
set /a variable%variabletwo%five=25
set /a variable%variablethree%six=36
goto three

:three
set /a variable%variableone%four+=(2*(!variable%variabletwo%five!-!!variable%variablethree%six!))
echo !variable%variableone%four!
set var
```

Now for me, what is being echoed is **-8** which is equal to 14+(2*(25-36))

So - works for me!

Comment: yeah that's the strange part. In my actual file when I manually put in %variabletwo% and %variablethree% for the equation and           %variableone% for the last line it works just fine but when I change it to a variable it can't find it, so I've looked over the whole thing word by word ,especially the variable itself, multiple times trying to find the source of the problem and I haven't found it yet but I know it has to be there somewhere.

Comment: After a few more searches back though my file I finally found that the problem was just an extra space in one of the variables. Thank you for your response.

Comment: to avoid such problems use `set "var=val"`